# How inserting LineStrings to a PostGIS-Database with Python, psycopg2 and ppygis

Tags: postgresql, python-2.7, geometry, postgis, psycopg2

i am trying to insert LineStrings to a local Postgres/PostGIS-database. I use Python 2.7, psycopg2 and ppygis.

Every time when i make a loop-input, only a few records were inserted into the table. I tried to find out the problem with mogrify, but i see no failure.

```
polyline = []
for row in positions:
   lat = row[0]
   lon = row[1]
   point = ppygis.Point(lon, lat, srid=4326)
   polyline.append(point)
linestring = ppygis.LineString(polyline, srid=4326)

self.cursor.execute("BEGIN")
self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO gtrack_4326 (car, polyline) VALUES (%s,%s);", ("TEST_car", linestring))
self.cursor.execute("COMMIT")
```

The use of execute.mogrify results in Strings like this:

```
INSERT INTO gtrack_4326 (car,polyline) VALUES ('TEST_car', '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');
```

But if i look into the Database, i see a lot of records without geometry-data in the second column. I did not understand why mogrify shows data in each column and in the DB there is in nearly 50 % of the table no data in the geometry-column.

Answer (score 1):

First, `psycopg2` does its own transaction management, so you should generally write:

```
self.cursor.execute(
    "INSERT INTO gtrack_4326 (car, polyline) VALUES (%s,%s);",
    ("TEST_car", linestring)
)
self.conn.commit()
```

See [the psycopg2 docs](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/connection.html#connection.commit).

Second, consider loading data in batches with `COPY`. See [`COPY` in the psycopg2 docs](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#using-copy-to-and-copy-from).

Also consider setting `log_statement = 'all'` in `postgresql.conf` and a suitable `log_line_prefix` then restarting the PostgreSQL server. Examine the logs and see if you can tell what's doing the bogus inserts.

If practical, add a `CHECK` and/or `NOT NULL` constraint to the geometry column so that any incorrect `INSERT`s will fail and report an error to the program doing the insert. This might help you diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 1):

How did you determine that 50% of the rows have no geometry data? I'll warn anyone using clients like pgAdminIII show a blank cell if it contains too much data, so it appears to be NULL, when it isn't. You can also directly view the GIS data in a program like Quantum GIS.

With an SQL client, a better diagnostic to determine if a linestring is really there is to get the [number of points in the linestring](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_NumPoints.html):

```
SELECT car, ST_NumPoints(polyline) FROM gtrack_4326;
```

If the numbers are empty, then your assessment is correct that they are empty. Otherwise, the data are too large to display in your client application.